# How to solve "TypeError: process.getuid is not a function"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, laravel, npm, webpack

I am running react.js with laravel and watching changes with `yarn run watch` which has worked fine until I began to come across this error with webpack any time I used yarn or npm after I made some windows 10 updates (I really don't know if that could be a reason) - I would love any help.

```
if (!e && fileOwnerId === process.getuid()) utimesSync(openCollectivePath, now, now)
```

**The error:**

```
TypeError: process.getuid is not a function at C:\project_path\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:352:43 at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:153:23)
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Was it by chance Monday when this happened? If so, I believe it's related to this issue:
https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/issues/962

From what I gather Webpack CLI which Laravel Mix uses tries to print a message once every six days asking the user to consider donating, but recent versions relied on a function that isn't available in Windows. The logic was originally added as a consideration for people who were bothered by constantly seeing the message, and later tweaked to avoid file permission issues for Mac and Linux users, but the latter change caused problems for Windows users only on Mondays.

[A solution proposed](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/issues/962#issuecomment-502946992) by the user rseeburg in that thread was simply to wrap the offending code in a try/catch. However, it looks like the donation message [has been removed](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/releases/tag/v3.3.5) as of Webpack CLI 3.3.5, so updating the package should fix it. I got it working again by adding `"webpack-cli": "^3.3.5"` to package.json followed by `yarn install`.

Comment: This seems to be the perfect solution, I'm marking it as the answer.

Comment: I'm running `webpack-cli v3.3.9` and just had this happen to me. I set my system clock to Tuesday and that fixed the issue for now

Answer (score 57):

I was just having this issue as well. I'm not sure what caused it, but deleting my node_modules folder and re-running "npm install" fixed it for me.

Comment: works! the issue happened to me after changing the name in package.json

Answer (score 0):

You can do 3 things to fix that :

**1**- by change you day to any day excepted Monday Because this function if

```
 const now = new Date();
if (now.getDay() === MONDAY) {
    const { access, constants, statSync, utimesSync } = require("fs");
    const lastPrint = statSync(openCollectivePath).atime;
    const lastPrintTS = new Date(lastPrint).getTime();
    const timeSinceLastPrint = now.getTime() - lastPrintTS;
    if (timeSinceLastPrint > SIX_DAYS) {
        require(openCollectivePath);
        // On windows we need to manually update the atime
        access(openCollectivePath, constants.W_OK, e => {
            if (!e) utimesSync(openCollectivePath, now, now);
        });
    }
}
```

and that about donating to their package

**2**- remove that condition `fileOwnerId === process.getuid())` ,  but it's Not Working for windows users so you can the last thing

**3**- add this     `"webpack-cli": "^3.3.5"` to your `package.json` in dependencies and run `npm` that working for me.

Answer (score 0):

simply running `npm install`
solved it for me. didn't have to delete any folders